# C++ add linux user

Tags: c++, c, linux, user-administration

Whats the best way to add a user/group in linux using C++ is there a library I can call on? I dont want to start doing things like:

```
fopen("/etc/passwd", "a");
 fprintf(tmp, "%s:x:%d:1:%s:/%s/%s:/bin/ksh\n", username, usernumber, commentfield, userdir, username);
 fclose(tmp);

fopen("/etc/shadow", "a");
 fprintf(stmp, "%s:*LK*:::::::\n", username);
 fclose(stmp);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've noticed that most major utilities that add and change users do so directly, often in different ways.  The functions you can use to modify the [passwd](http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd) and shadow files are exposed in [`<pwd.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/pwd.h.html) and in `<sys/types.h>`, and [they're part of glibc](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_25.html).

[fgetpwent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetpwent), [getpwnam](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam), [getpw](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpw), [getpwent_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwent_r), [putpwent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putpwent), [setpwent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setpwent)

We can look into how busybox (via [TinyLogin](http://tinylogin.busybox.net/)) does it, as an example.  In [`busybox/loginutils/adduser.c`](http://svn.dd-wrt.com:8000/dd-wrt/browser/src/router/busybox/loginutils/adduser.c?rev=9719), they put a user in the passwd file by building the passwd structure and then call `putpwent`.  For adding the user's password in the shadow file, they simply call `fprintf` and write the string directly.

For authenticating users the modern way, there's [Linux-PAM](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_ADG.html).  But as far as adding users, you can see in [pam_unix_passwd.c](http://devel.blueonyx.it/trac/browser/BlueQuartz/5100WG/branches/dev/ui/sauce-basic.mod/src/pam_pwdb/pam_unix_passwd.-c?rev=1) that they call [unix_update_db()](http://devel.blueonyx.it/trac/browser/BlueQuartz/5100WG/branches/dev/ui/sauce-basic.mod/src/pam_pwdb/pam_unix_passwd.-c?rev=1), which calls various functions in [libpwdb](http://www.koders.com/c/fid1400F753E2C2071C9B428A336C3B2B03A181D155.aspx?s=search#L26), which you'd have to add as a dependency to your project if you use it.

That being said, I'm guilty of having written a couple utilities to parse the passwd and shadow databases and modify them directly.  It worked fine, but this was on an embedded system where I could tightly control everything.  I didn't have to worry about things like race conditions with other programs modifying the passwd db.

If you need to add a group, same goes for the [group database](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_25.html#SEC446).

Answer (score 5):

You might try using the [libuser](https://fedorahosted.org/libuser/) library.

One of the applications that are distributed with libuser is `luseradd`, a program that appears to be a cross-platform `useradd` utility. At its core, `luseradd` uses libuser's `lu_user_add` function to physically create the user.

See the `docs/html` folder in the source distribution for documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a user is a bit too high-level for there to be a system call for it. As far as I'm aware, there aren't any widely used libraries for this either. Your best bet will probably be to use the `system` call to invoke the `useradd` program with appropriate options.

Comment: Few things:

* Don't use system() unless you're very sure that things you pass won't be interpreted as special characters by the shell.
* useradd isn't particularly portable (and on some systems you may not be able to create a "normal" user, e.g. one where users are in LDAP/NIS/AD/etc.

In general, for one-off user creation I'd use a shell script.